# Can Mapbox's MapSnapshotter be used to generate a bitmap containing annotations?

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm attempting to use `MapSnapshotter` (a part of the [Mapbox Maps SDK for Android](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/snapshotter/)) to generate a screenshot of a Mapbox map instance, including a single line annotation that I've added to the map.

I seem to be able to generate a static map bitmap as expected, however the image does not contain my line annotation.

Is there a way of having the line appear in the bitmap that `MapSnapshotter` generates, or is `MapSnapshotter` limited to capturing map screenshots sans annotations?

I'm using the [example code](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/snapshot/SnapshotShareActivity.java) provided in one of Mapbox's repositories for the moment. The only alterations that I've made are to add a new layer and source to the Mapbox map style such that it is displayed on the interactive Mapbox map.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have any symbols/geometries visible on the snapshot taken with the `MapSnapshotter`, the desired layers would have to be added directly to the style. Alternatively, you can draw on top of the image like in [this example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-android/blob/master/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/testapp/activity/snapshot/MapSnapshotterBitMapOverlayActivity.java), which adds a marker to a snapshot.

Another way is to render a normal, interactive map and take a picture of it with `MapboxMap#snapshot`.

Comment: Link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

Please tell how to add the desired layer directly to the style according above answer?
I added my custom symbol layer to mapbox style, but snapshot does not make bitmap with symbols.

```
FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromJson(geoJson);
Source source = new GeoJsonSource("my.data.source", featureCollection);
mapboxMap.addSource(source);

SymbolLayer myLayer = new SymbolLayer("my.layer.id", "my.source.id");
myLayer.withProperties(PropertyFactory.iconImage("my.image"));
mapboxMap.addLayer(myLayer);

// ...
MapSnapshotter.Options snapShotOptions = new MapSnapshotter.Options(500, 500);

snapShotOptions.withRegion(mapboxMap.getProjection()
.getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds);

snapShotOptions.withStyle(mapboxMap.getStyle().getUrl());

MapSnapshotter mapSnapshotter = new MapSnapshotter(this, snapShotOptions);
```

Thank you.